# Odoo font size for POS

Tags: python, css, odoo, point-of-sale

We have a very small table for the point of sales of our ODOO installation. We need to customize the size of the font so that it's bigger than the default one when the products are loaded to the POS. I have tried to increase the font for the browser in the tablet and it does not work.

I have also being playing with the user interfaces, but I can't figure out wish one do I have to modify to make it happen.

Does any one has any idea about how to achieve this?

Comment: do you want increase the font size only tablets?

Comment: Yes, I have managed to modify the css called product-name of the point of sales, but it won't modify the way it looks on a tablet, but only on bigger screens.

Comment: Well I am talking about my tablets, with chrome.